# How to tail iOS device log without debugger attached?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, apple-push-notifications

I've encountered a bug that only occurs when my app is cold-started in response to a certain type of remote notification.

In order to faithfully reproduce the bug, I need to be on a real device so that I receive the notification, and because it happens on cold-start I can't have the debugger attached to the process.

Is there any conceivable way for me to get access to the console log (preferably in real-time)?

I've tried this solution: https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx
but it does not seem to work on the latest version of MacOS. 
(I get the error `usbmuxd_send: Error -1 when sending: Broken pipe`x2)

PS- I know I can use the Xcode "devices" window, but there is a ton of noise in there, and I can't filter it in real-time AFAIK

Thanks

Comment: The two approaches I've employed in the past include: 1. Log messages to a text file in the Documents folder of the app (which you can then examine when you use the "Download Container" feature in Xcode's Devices window). I guess you could use CloudKit if you want to automate the download process. 2. Add tableview in app that allows me to review a list of message (reverse chronological order is useful) which is enabled only when debugging. Neither of those are great solutions, but they're both admittedly better than pouring through the device console seen via the Devices window, IMHO.

Comment: @Rob. Where is download container nowadays in Xcode 8.2? I can't find it anywhere in devices. P.S. It would be wonderful if you ever got round to writing a Swift/iOS 10 version of pushing the limits.

Comment: Select the device, then select the app on the device, and then tap on the gear icon...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best *reliable* way to do this is to use the Xcode devices window, clear the output, then reproduce the bug and finally copy and paste the entire output into a separate file.

Once in the separate file you can filter using grep or a similar tool.

It isn't perfect but it works every time for me. Setting up very noticeable logging statements help as well.